# dbus signals for monitor power off/on?

Tags: python, linux-mint, dbus

I'm interested in determining when my system is idle via dbus messages. I've used dbus-monitor (both system and session buses) but found nothing. Is there a signal for monitor power off or for user not present between keyboard and chair?

I'm currently able to subscribe to screen saver messages using Python:

```
# subscribe to dbus screensaver
session_bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION, None)
session_bus.signal_subscribe('org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver',
                            'org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver',
                            'ActiveChanged',
                            '/org/cinnamon/ScreenSaver',
                            None,
                            Gio.DBusSignalFlags.NONE,
                            onActiveChanged,
                            None)
```